# How to validate form input data in Javascript using JSON information

Tags: javascript, html, json

I would like to validate my form inputs with data in a JSON file using JavaScript. The goal is to make sure the user enters the correct `clnt_key` data that matches information in the JSON file. How do I do that?

```html
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Client key">
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:validate()" class="btn btn-danger btn">Login</button>

</form>
```

This is the JavaScript code that doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```html
<script>
  function validate() {

    $.getJSON("clientkey.json", function(data) {


      $.each(data.response.message.org_details, function(key, value) {

        if (document.getElementById("text1").value == "CLNT_KEY") {
          alert("validation succeeded");
          location.href = "login.html";
        } else {
          alert("validation failed");
          location.href = "fail.html";
        }

      });

    });
  }
</script>
```

Here is my JSON file

```js
{
  "response": "yes",
  "message": "Client Key Exists",
  "org_details": {
    "ENTY_ID": 31,
    "ORG_LGL_NME": "Patterson Park Neighborhood Association",
    "ORG_NME": "Patterson Park Neighborhood Association",
    "ORG_DESC": null,
    "CLNT_KEY": "PPNA2017",
    "ADMN_KEY": "appna2017",
    "FED_TAX_ID": null,
    "ORG_INDST_CD": 20,
    "ORG_ANNL_REVN_AMT": null,
    "ORG_INCORP_CNTRY_CD": 840
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking fora method like csrf_token?
https://www.veracode.com/security/csrf-token

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$.each(data.response.message.org_details, function(key, value){

    if (key === "CLNT_KEY" && document.getElementById("text1").value === value)
    {
        alert( "validation succeeded" );
        location.href="login.html";
    }
    else
    {
        alert( "validation failed" );
        location.href="fail.html";
    }

});
```